# latex equations in tables with quarto/revealjs?

Tags: html, latex, kableextra, quarto, reveal.js

I am using quarto with revealjs to make a presentation in rstudio.
Code is as follows

````
---
title: "table_latex"
format: revealjs
---

## Quarto


```{r}
library(readr)
tbl1 <- read_csv("table.csv")
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra) 

kbl(tbl1, escape = FALSE) %>%
  kable_classic(full_width = F) %>%
    kable_styling(font_size = 24) %>%
      row_spec(2, color = "lightgray", background = "darkred")
```
````

`table.csv` is something like this:

```
var, val
$a$, 1
$b$, 2
$c$, 3
```

The output within rstudio looks fine, the rendered html looks bad.
[image]

Why the output is not the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why your approach is not working, but it seems if you save the table in a variable and then `cat()` it along with `results: asis`, it works!! (Not sure why this workaround is needed though).

````
---
title: "table_latex"
format: revealjs
---

## Quarto


```{r}
library(readr)
library(kableExtra) 

tbl1 <- read_csv("table.csv")
```


```{r}
#| results: asis
tab <- kbl(tbl1) %>%
  kable_classic(full_width = F) %>%
    kable_styling(font_size = 24) %>%
      row_spec(2, color = "lightgray", background = "darkred")

cat(tab)
```
````

---

[image: math equation in kableExtra table]

Comment: Works ... but I am also using a citation in the title with `#| tbl-cap: Tabla 1 de [@Weik2000].` and the citation along with the entire title disappear. Also the table gets smaller...

Comment: Hi @murpholinox, I would suggest to post a separate question regarding this issue.